# RecyclerView custom animation while scrolling

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I have a `RecyclerView` with multiple `CardViews`. These I expand and collapse by using this code in my `onBindViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
 
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.hiddenLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(holder.cardView,
                        new AutoTransition());
                holder.hiddenLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(holder.cardView,
                        new AutoTransition());
                holder.hiddenLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My Problem is, when I scroll while the animation takes place the cards get badly brought up and become extremely warped. How can I avoid that to happen?

Answer (score -1):

This is a common mistake.handling your onclick listener inside onbindviewholder method is not the best idea.try to handle your click listeners in your viewholder class.

Comment: Okay, thank you for that advice! Unfortunately it doesn’t solve my problem